# Manejo de decimales en jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

¿Cómo puedo agregar decimales a las columnas de mi DataTable? Por ejemplo, quiero mostrar 0.00.
[image: Mi Tabla]

Mi codigo

```
jQuery('#cuentas').DataTable( {
            data: datos.data,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "codProducto" },
                { "data": "codCuenta" },
                { "data": "nomProducto" },
                { "data": "valSaldo",},
                { "data": "valEfectivo" },
                { "data": "valCheques" },
                { "data": "valBloqueado" }
            ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes ocupar render para aplicarselo a las columnas

```
{ "name": "valSaldo", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar la configuración `lenguage`

```
jQuery('#cuentas').DataTable( {
          "language": {
                      "decimal": ".",//separador decimales
                      "thousands": ","//Separador miles
            },
            data: datos.data,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "codProducto" },
                { "data": "codCuenta" },
                { "data": "nomProducto" },
                { "data": "valSaldo",},
                { "data": "valEfectivo" },
                { "data": "valCheques" },
                { "data": "valBloqueado" }
            ],
```